# Is it possible to debug Android apps on Acer Liquid E from Windows 7?

Tags: remote-debugging, logcat, android, android-logcat

I'd like to buy an [Acer Liquid E](http://www.gsmarena.com/acer_liquid_e-3156.php) as an Android test phone (normal size, high density screen, android v2.1 up to 2.2).

Before actually doing that, it'll be great to know if anyone had any bad experience with it. My dev environment is Eclipse + ADT on Windows 7 64 bits. I'm thinking about things like USB drivers, logcat displayed correctly, breakpoints hit, and so on.

I read about this [issue](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/Ex8pp9ptRbk), but it's from 2009 and in the end it was solved anyway.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not exactly **the** answer to this question, but I'll post it in case it might be useful for some other developer in need.

In the end I did not go into buying this exact phone model. Instead I bought an [Acer Liquid MT S120 (or Metal)](http://www.gsmarena.com/acer_liquid_mt-3519.php) phone. In order to be able to debug apps on it, I just had to look for official Acer Windows drivers.

Those where relatively easy to find ([here](http://global-download.acer.com/GDFiles/Application/Application/Application_Acer_1.0_A22F_A.zip?acerid=634261811335479139&Step1=Smart%20Handheld&Step2=Liquid&Step3=Liquid%20MT%20%28S120%29&OS=a04&LC=it&BC=Acer&SC=EMEA_17) version 1.0): the only quirk was that I had to select the former Android version (2.2 instead of actual 2.3) in order to see the drivers under the *Application* tab, otherwise they would not show.

Apart from that, debugging experience was very straightforward: plug USB in, and Eclipse/adb where able to see the device. APK upload times are really fast (I guess this holds for any USB-connected device too). The same holds for integration/functional tests.